# Why does longer vAxis label in google chart appends 3 dots ( . ) at the end

Tags: google-visualization

I have a google chart that has a vAxis setting as below ..

```
vAxis: {
            textStyle: { color: 'white' },
            baselineColor: '#666666',
            format: '######.#'
        },
```

but longer than 1000 integer in vAxis label append 3 dots ( . ) and not showing the entire lable, so like if the actual label is 2000 then it is only showing 2... Can anyone please advise how could I show entire label 2000 instead of 2...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google calculate the width of the label and make the adjustment in label in terms of adding dots at the end. So workaround would be increasing chart width or decreasing label font size. I decreased the font size and that did the tricks :)